# Converting a SQL query to an XQuery that counts Bi-yearly sales.

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql

im having trouble with getting a an XQuery to count the sales over two years, it's based upon an SQL Query.

```
SELECT [ShipCountry] & " " & [ShipCity] AS CountryAndCity, COUNT(OrderID) AS BiYearlySales
FROM Orders
WHERE (((OrderDate) BETWEEN #1/1/1996# And #1/1/1998#))
GROUP BY [ShipCountry] & " " & [ShipCity];
```

This is the xquery i've got so far but it only counts each instance once. Cant figure out why.
I'm using Altova xmlspy - xquery 1.0 for it.

```
<Result>
{
for $a in doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Orders
let $b := concat($a/ShipCountry, " ", $a/ShipCity)
where $a/OrderDate >= '1996-01-01T00:00:00' and $a/OrderDate <= '1998-01-01T00:00:00'
return
<BiYearlySales>
    <CountryNameAndCity>{$b}</CountryNameAndCity>
    <OrderCount>{count($a)}</OrderCount>
</BiYearlySales>
}
</Result>
```

I realize I haven't done the group by yet, but trying to get this working is of more importance.

Comment: FYI, we have two other people asking for help with the exact same homework. It might be helpful to look at other recent questions tagged xquery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is exactly right...(haven't tried it) but something like this:

```
for $country in doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Orders[OrderDate ge '1996-01-01T00:00:00' and OrderDate le '1998-01-01T00:00:00']/ShipCountry, $city in doc(doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Orders[OrderDate ge '1996-01-01T00:00:00' and OrderDate le '1998-01-01T00:00:00']/ShipCity")
return 
<sales>
   <geo>{$country, " ", $city)}</geo>
   <count>{count(doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Orders
           [OrderDate ge '1996-01-01T00:00:00' and OrderDate le '1998-01-01T00:00:00' 
            and ShipCountry eq $country and ShipCity eq $city])}
   </count>
</sales>
```